# Duplicate the row when there is same dict key while convert list of dict into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, etl

I am facing an issue when converting a column with a list of multiple dicts into a separate pandas DataFrame. When converting the list of dicts, the same keys in different dictionaries are being overwritten by the value of the last key.

Dataframe:

```
   Column1        Column2
0  std_123        [{
                       'id': '14633',
                       'id_name': 'Color',
                       'id_value': '86942',
                       'id_value_name': 'Yellow'
                   },
                   {
                       'id': '44974',
                       'id_name': 'sub_color',
                       'id_value': '2752911',
                       'id_value_name': 'Greenish Yellow'
                   }]
```

When i tried to create new dataframe from column2

```
df_c = df['Column2'].apply(pd.Series)
```

It gives me a dataframe like

```
id     id_name   value
44974  sub_color Greenish Yellow
```

Where as i want the dataframe like

```
column1  id     id_name   value
std_123  14633  Color     Yellow
std_123  44974  sub_color Greenish Yellow
```

Comment: `df["Column2"].explode().apply(pd.Series)`?

Answer (score 1):

Given your dataframe(let's call it df)

```
  Column1        Column2
0  std_123        [{
                       'id': '14633',
                       'id_name': 'Color',
                       'id_value': '86942',
                       'id_value_name': 'Yellow'
                   },
                   {
                       'id': '44974',
                       'id_name': 'sub_color',
                       'id_value': '2752911',
                       'id_value_name': 'Greenish Yellow'
                   }]
```

Use the following to get the desired dataframe

```
l = [y for x in df["Column2"] for y in x] 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(l)
```